# More object oriented results from Solr and nullable database

Tags: database, solr, dataimporthandler, solr4

Lets assume that I have this configuration:

**data-import-handler-config.xml**

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/solr" user="root" password="" batchSize="-1" />
    <document>
        <entity name="Book" query="select id, title from Book;">
            <field column="title" name="title" />
            <entity name="Author" query="select name, alias from Author where id='${Book.id}'">
                <field name="name" column="name" />
                <field name="alias" column="alias" />
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

**schema.xml**

```
<fields>
    <field name="_version_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <!-- general -->
    <field name="title" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="name" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
    <field name="alias" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
</fields>
```

Result which I got from Solr (in xml format) looks like this:

```
<doc>
    <str name="title">Book with good title</str>
    <arr name="name">
        <str>John Doe 1</str>
        <str>John Doe 2</str>
        <str>John Doe 3</str>
    </arr>
    <arr name="alias">
        <bool>false</str>
        <bool>false</str>
        <bool>True</str>
    </arr>
</doc>
```

And there is nothing wrong with this as long as all fileds in database **are not NULL**.

When some of alias is set to NULL, I got for instance:

```
<doc>
    <str name="title">Book with good title</str>
    <arr name="name">
        <str>John Doe 1</str>
        <str>John Doe 2</str>
        <str>John Doe 3</str>
    </arr>
    <arr name="alias">
        <bool>True</str>
    </arr>
</doc>
```

However I don't know alias of which author was set to null.

**1) Is It possible to keep NULLs in database and import data to Solr without a problem?**

I think it would be much simpler to get data in a little more "object oriented" format, like this:

```
<doc>
    <str name="title">Book with good title</str>
    <authors>
        <author>
            <str name="name">John Doe 1</str>
            <bool name="alias">false</bool>
        </author>
        <author>
            <str name="name">John Doe 2</str>
            <bool name="alias">false</bool>
        </author>
        <author>
            <str name="name">John Doe 3</str>
            <bool name="alias">True</bool>
        </author>
    <authors>
</doc>
```

**2) Can "object oriented" style be achieved by using custom Solr Field?**